# How to check if a view controller is presented modally or pushed on a navigation stack?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

How can I, in my view controller code, differentiate between:

- presented modally
- pushed on navigation stack

Both `presentingViewController` and `isMovingToParentViewController` are `YES` in both cases, so are not very helpful.

What complicates things is that my parent view controller is sometimes modal, on which the to be checked view controller is pushed.

It turns out my issue is that I embed my `HtmlViewController` in a `UINavigationController` which is then presented. That's why my own attempts and the good answers below were not working.

```
HtmlViewController*     termsViewController = [[HtmlViewController alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary];
UINavigationController* modalViewController;

modalViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:termsViewController];
modalViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:modalViewController
                   animated:YES
                 completion:nil];
```

I guess I'd better tell my view controller when it's modal, instead of trying to determine.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Take with a grain of salt, didn't test.

```
- (BOOL)isModal {
     if([self presentingViewController])
         return YES;
     if([[[self navigationController] presentingViewController] presentedViewController] == [self navigationController])
         return YES;
     if([[[self tabBarController] presentingViewController] isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]])
         return YES;

    return NO;
 }
```

Comment: `presentingViewController` returns `YES` for pushed VC, when there is a `UITabBarController` being set as a root. So, does not suitable in my case.

Answer (score 112):

In **Swift**:

Add a flag to test if it's a modal by the class type:

```
// MARK: - UIViewController implementation

extension UIViewController {

    var isModal: Bool {

        let presentingIsModal = presentingViewController != nil
        let presentingIsNavigation = navigationController?.presentingViewController?.presentedViewController == navigationController
        let presentingIsTabBar = tabBarController?.presentingViewController is UITabBarController

        return presentingIsModal || presentingIsNavigation || presentingIsTabBar
    }
}
```

Comment: you need change to let presentingIsNavigation = navigationController?.presentingViewController?.presentedViewController == navigationController && navigationController != nil

Comment: Swift 5: presentingIsNavigation = true if navigationController is nil

Answer (score 94):

You overlooked one method: `isBeingPresented`.

`isBeingPresented` is true when the view controller is being presented and false when being pushed.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if ([self isBeingPresented]) {
        // being presented
    } else if ([self isMovingToParentViewController]) {
        // being pushed
    } else {
        // simply showing again because another VC was dismissed
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this too before posting, and it does not work, `isBeingPresented` is `NO`. But I see the reason now, I'm embedding my presented view controller in a `UINavigationController`, and that's the one I'm pushing.

Comment: You can't push a navigation controller. Perhaps you meant that you are presenting the navigation controller.

Comment: Documentation for `isBeingPresented` - This method returns YES only when called from inside the viewWillAppear: and viewDidAppear: methods.

Comment: Yes, I meant that I present the `UINavigationController`.

Comment: @BridgeTheGap What documentation are you referring to? I don't see this in the UIViewController Overview nor on the property reference itself.

Comment: @Terrence It seems the latest documentation doesn't show that information but it used to be there. The `isBeingPresented`, `isBeingDismissed`, `isMovingFromParentViewController` and `isMovingToParentViewController` are only valid inside the 4 `view[Will|Did][Disa|A]ppear` methods.

Comment: `isBeingPresented` works in other situations but seems to give inconsistent results.  Ex. After presenting a popover from within the UITextFieldDelegate method, textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:, 
isBeingPresented correctly returned YES while still within the scope of that method call, but the next time that method was called it return NO even though the popover was still being presented.

Answer (score 45):

**Swift 5**
Here is solution that addresses the issue mentioned with previous answers, when `isModal()` returns `true` if pushed `UIViewController` is in a presented `UINavigationController` stack.

```
extension UIViewController {
    var isModal: Bool {
        if let index = navigationController?.viewControllers.firstIndex(of: self), index > 0 {
            return false
        } else if presentingViewController != nil {
            return true
        } else if navigationController?.presentingViewController?.presentedViewController == navigationController {
            return true
        } else if tabBarController?.presentingViewController is UITabBarController {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

It does work for me so far.
If some optimizations, please share.

Comment: Why do you need to check `tabBarController?.presentingViewController is UITabBarController `? Does it matter if that `presentingViewController` is also a UITabBarController?

Comment: And if navigationController is nil, `isModal` will return `true`. Is this intended?

Answer (score 35):

> self.navigationController != nil would mean it's in a navigation
> stack.

In order to handle the case that the current view controller is pushed while the navigation controller is presented modally, I have added some lines of code to check if the current view controller is the root controller in the navigation stack .

```
extension UIViewController {
    var isModal: Bool {
        if let index = navigationController?.viewControllers.firstIndex(of: self), index > 0 {
            return false
        } else if presentingViewController != nil {
            return true
        } else if let navigationController = navigationController, navigationController.presentingViewController?.presentedViewController == navigationController {
            return true
        } else if let tabBarController = tabBarController, tabBarController.presentingViewController is UITabBarController {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well in general when you present modally, you put the viewController on a navigationController and you present it. If that is the case your statement would be wrong, however on the code this case is handled. Please improve your answer :)

Answer (score 21):

**Swift 5.** Clean and simple.

```
if navigationController?.presentingViewController != nil {
    // Navigation controller is being presented modally
}
```

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 4**

```
var isModal: Bool {
    return presentingViewController != nil ||
           navigationController?.presentingViewController?.presentedViewController === navigationController ||
           tabBarController?.presentingViewController is UITabBarController
}
```

Comment: Swift 4.2 / iOS 12. Still works well, but be aware that navigationController?.presentingViewController?.presentedViewController === navigationController will evaluate to true if both are nil (for example, if you call it on a view controller that has not yet been presented).

Answer (score 9):

***Swift 5***
This handy extension handles few more cases than previous answers. These cases are VC(view controller) is the root VC of app window, VC is added as child to parent VC. It tries to return true only if the viewcontroller is modally presented.

```
extension UIViewController {
    /**
      returns true only if the viewcontroller is presented.
    */
    var isModal: Bool {
        if let index = navigationController?.viewControllers.firstIndex(of: self), index > 0 {
            return false
        } else if presentingViewController != nil {
            if let parent = parent, !(parent is UINavigationController || parent is UITabBarController) {
                return false
            }
            return true
        } else if let navController = navigationController, navController.presentingViewController?.presentedViewController == navController {
            return true
        } else if tabBarController?.presentingViewController is UITabBarController {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Thanks to [Jonauz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43020070). Again there is space for more optimizations. Please discuss about case that need to be handled in comment section.

Comment: doesn't work for swiftui cases. There is parent UIHostingControll<BridgedNavigationView.RootView> or event somthing else if swiftui view is presented without navigation view via UIViewContorllerRepresentable

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that all viewControllers that you present modally are wrapped inside a new navigationController (which you should always do anyway), you can add this property to your VC.

```
private var wasPushed: Bool {
    guard let vc = navigationController?.viewControllers.first where vc == self else {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: _which you should always do anyway_ - please explain why?

Answer (score 3):

As many folks here suggest, that "checking" methods don't work well for all cases, in my project I've come up with solution to manage that manually.
The point is, we usually manage presentation on our own - this is not what happens behind the scene and we must to introspect.

`DEViewController.h` file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

// it is a base class for all view controllers within a project
@interface DEViewController : UIViewController 

// specify a way viewcontroller, is presented  by another viewcontroller
// the presented view controller should manually assign the value to it
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, SSViewControllerPresentationMethod) {
    SSViewControllerPresentationMethodUnspecified = 0,
    SSViewControllerPresentationMethodPush,
    SSViewControllerPresentationMethodModal,
};
@property (nonatomic) SSViewControllerPresentationMethod viewControllerPresentationMethod;

// other properties/methods...
@end
```

The presentations now could be managed this way:

**pushed on navigation stack:**

```
// DETestViewController inherits from DEViewController
DETestViewController *vc = [DETestViewController new];
vc.viewControllerPresentationMethod = SSViewControllerPresentationMethodPush;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

**presented modally with navigation:**

```
DETestViewController *vc = [DETestViewController new];
vc.viewControllerPresentationMethod = SSViewControllerPresentationMethodModal;
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                               initWithRootViewController:vc];
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**presented modally:**

```
DETestViewController *vc = [DETestViewController new];
vc.viewControllerPresentationMethod = SSViewControllerPresentationMethodModal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Also, in `DEViewController` we could add a fallback to "checking" if the aforementioned property equals to `SSViewControllerPresentationMethodUnspecified`:

```
- (BOOL)isViewControllerPushed
{
    if (self.viewControllerPresentationMethod != SSViewControllerPresentationMethodUnspecified) {
        return (BOOL)(self.viewControllerPresentationMethod == SSViewControllerPresentationMethodPush);
    }

    else {
        // fallback to default determination method
        return (BOOL)self.navigationController.viewControllers.count > 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ios 5.0 or later than please use this code

```
-(BOOL)isPresented
{
    if ([self isBeingPresented]) {
        // being presented
         return YES;
    } else if ([self isMovingToParentViewController]) {
        // being pushed
         return NO;
    } else {
        // simply showing again because another VC was dismissed
         return NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To detect your controller is pushed or not just use below code in anywhere you want:

```
if ([[[self.parentViewController childViewControllers] firstObject] isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {

    // Not pushed
}
else {

    // Pushed
}
```

I hope this code can help anyone...

Comment: This method does not work when you use same view controller class in multiple places, since it does check only the class of it. You can explicitly check the equality instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
if let navigationController = self.navigationController, navigationController.isBeingPresented {
    // being presented
}else{
    // being pushed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some one who's wondering, How to tell ViewController that it is being presented

if `A` is presenting/pushing `B`

1. Define an `enum` and `property` in `B`

   ```
   enum ViewPresentationStyle {
       case Push
       case Present
   }

   //and write property 

   var vcPresentationStyle : ViewPresentationStyle = .Push //default value, considering that B is pushed
   ```
2. Now in `A` view controller, tell `B` if it is being presented/pushed by assigning `presentationStyle`

   ```
   func presentBViewController() {
       let bViewController = B()
       bViewController.vcPresentationStyle = .Present //telling B that it is being presented
       self.presentViewController(bViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```
3. Usage in `B` View Controller

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       if self.vcPresentationStyle == .Present {
           //is being presented 
       }
       else {
           //is being pushed
       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution - tested under iOS 15 and Xcode 13.1:

```swift
var isPresented: Bool {
    if let nvc = navigationController {
        return nvc.viewControllers.firstIndex(of: self) == 0
    } else {
        return presentingViewController != nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`self.navigationController != nil` would mean it's in a navigation stack.

Comment: Can still be in a modal navigation controller

Comment: @Daniel The difference is between "pushed" and "presented". "Modal' has nothing to do with it. I believe "ColdLogic" meant "presented" when they said "modal".

Answer (score -3):

```
id presentedController = self.navigationController.modalViewController;
if (presentedController) {
     // Some view is Presented
} else {
     // Some view is Pushed
}
```

This will let you know if viewController is presented or pushed

Comment: This property is deprecated.