# How to correctly dismiss a UINavigationController that's presented as a modal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In my `TabBarViewController`, I create a UINavigationController and present it as a modal.

```
var navController =  UINavigationController()
let messageVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MessagesViewController") as! MessagesViewController
self.presentViewController(self.navController, animated: false, completion: nil)
self.navController.pushViewController(messageVC, animated: false)
```

Inside my `MessageViewController`, this is how I want to dismiss it:

```
func swipedRightAndUserWantsToDismiss(){
    if self == self.navigationController?.viewControllers[0] {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) //doesn't deinit
    }else{
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true) //deinits correctly
    }
}

deinit{
    print("Deinit MessagesViewController")
}
```

The problem is that when I get to the root View Controller and try to dismiss both the child and the UINavigationController, my `MessagesViewController` deinit does not get called.  Something's holding on to it -- most likely UINavigationController

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your controller hierarchy looks like this:

```
UITabViewController
    |
    | presents
    |
UINavigationController
    |
    | contains view controllers
    |
[root, MessagesViewController]
```

Now, if you are inside `MessagesViewController`, then its `navigationController` is the one that is being presented and that's the one you should be dismissing but calling `dismiss` on `MessagesViewController` should work too.

However, the problem is that dismissing the navigation controller won't remove its view controllers. It seems you are holding to your navigation controller (since you are presenting it using `self.navController`) so the state will become

```
UITabViewController
    |
    | self.navController holds a reference to
    |
UINavigationController
    |
    | contains view controllers
    |
[root, MessagesViewController]
```

To properly destroy `MessagesViewController` you will have to either let go of the `navController` or you will have to pop to root (thus removing `MessagesViewController` from view hierarchy).

The typical solution would be not to save a reference to `navController` at all. You could always create a new `UINavigationController` when presenting.
Another solution is using a delegate - instead of dismissing from inside `MessagesViewController`, let it call back to the presenter, which would call

```
self.navController.dismiss(animated: true) {
     self.navController = nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I have many view controllers in the stack, but my delegate calls ```dismissViewControllerAnimated``` and then sets it to nil , will it deinit **all** of the view controllers in the stack?

Comment: When you let go of all references to `navController`, all its view controllers will be destroyed if you are not holding to them somewhere else.

Comment: You also won't be able to dismiss a view controller that has been set as a rootviewcontroller. So, if:

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
func swipedRightAndUserWantsToDismiss(){
    self.navigationController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion:nil);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following to correctly dismiss a `UINavigationController` that's presented as a modal in Swift 4:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 5):

if you want to just present a viewcontroller, then directly you can present that viewcontroller and no need to take a navigation controller for that particular viewcontroller.

But when we need to navigate from that presented view controller then we need to take a view controller as a root view of navigation controller. So that we can navigate from that presented view controller.

```
let messageVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MessagesViewController") as! MessagesViewController
let MynavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: messageVC)
self.presentViewController(MynavController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and from that presented view controller, you can push to another view controller and also pop from another view controller.

And from presented view controller, here `messageVC`, we have to dismiss that as

```
func swipedRightAndUserWantsToDismiss() {
  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

which will dismiss `messageVC` successfully and come back to origin viewcontroller from where we have presented `messageVC`.

This is the right flow to perform `presentViewController` with navigation controller, to continue the navigation between the view controllers.

And for more if you are not sure that messageVC is presented or pushed, then you can check it [by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620276/check-if-view-controller-is-presented-modally-or-pushed-on-a-navigation-stack).

And the swift version to check that is

```
func isModal() -> Bool {
    if((self.presentingViewController) != nil) {
        return true
    }

    if(self.presentingViewController?.presentedViewController == self) {
        return true
    }

    if(self.navigationController?.presentingViewController?.presentedViewController == self.navigationController) {
        return true
    }

    if((self.tabBarController?.presentingViewController?.isKindOfClass(UITabBarController)) != nil) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

So our final action to dismiss is like

```
func swipedRightAndUserWantsToDismiss() {

            if self.isModal() == true {
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else {
                self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 4):

No need to have member for navController. Use following code to present your MessagesViewController.

```
let messageVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MessagesViewController") as! MessagesViewController
let pesentingNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: messageVC)
self.presentViewController(pesentingNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Your dismiss view controller code will be

```
func swipedRightAndUserWantsToDismiss() {
  self.navigationController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the other initializer for your `UINavigationController`:

```
let messageVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MessagesViewController") as! MessagesViewController
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: messageVC)
self.presentViewController(self.navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

To dimiss, simply do

```
func swipedRightAndUserWantsToDismiss() {
  self.navigationController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solve the problem in Objective C.

You can call **dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO** on your **self.navigationController** itself.

**Objective C**

```
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

**Swift**

```
self.navigationController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3 this is achieved with:

```
self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```