# Why is dismissing uinavigationcontroller not releasing view controller memory?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uidocument

Implementing `UIDocumentBrowserViewController` in an existing app. This vc, in iOS 11 is the root view controller, and tapping a file creates my doc, instantiates my view controller, and presents it inside a `UINavigationController`. It all works, in that the files display, the proper document opens, the vc displays and works as expected. I had to add a left button to the nav bar to provide a way to close the doc/vc.

When I tap the "Done" button, the view controller closes and returns to the document browser. All of that is good.

The problem is that the view controller's memory isn't releasing (and the domino effect of document memory, etc then not releasing). In the iOS 10 side of things, with a `UICollectionViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController` as the initial vc, but the doc and the display vc identical code for iOS 10 & 11, all memory releases. I've studied [How to correctly dismiss a UINavigationController that's presented as a modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416525/how-to-correctly-dismiss-a-uinavigationcontroller-thats-presented-as-a-modal) and related posts, tried dozens of alternatives, and am just not seeing what I'm missing. Instruments isn't showing any memory leaks, though I see document objects in memory after dismissing the view controller. The log shows that the vc's `viewWillDisappear` is being called at the proper time.

I appreciate any insights into why the vc memory isn't being released (`deinit()` not being called).

Thank you.

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
class DocumentBrowserViewController: UIDocumentBrowserViewController, UIDocumentBrowserViewControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    delegate = self

    allowsDocumentCreation = true
    allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
}

// MARK: Document Presentation

func returnToDocumentBrowser(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("returnToDocumentBrowser")
    if let controller = self.presentedViewController as? UINavigationController {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func presentDocument(at documentURL: URL) {
    print("present document")

    let doc = MyDocument(fileURL: documentURL)
    doc.open(completionHandler: { (success) in
        if (success) {
            print("open succeeded")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let myController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "my controller") as! MyViewController
                myController.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.returnToDocumentBrowser(sender:))), animated: false)
                myController.doc = doc

                let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myController)
                self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        } else {
            print("open failed")
        }
    })
}
}
```

Comment: maybe you have a retain cycle in your closure implementation, try using `[weak self]` before `(success) in` and use self.present with optional ? like this `self?.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)`let me know

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It didn't change the behavior. I also tried [unowned self] be/c I can never keep straight when they're needed or not...it's a mental block. No effect from either.

Comment: where is the `delegate` declaration? is weak?

Comment: You get it that way when you create a document based project in XCode 9. That line is part of what's provided for you. I did cut out from this post some of the delegate methods, as I didn't modify them from their default.

Comment: can you post this `delegate` property declaration?

Comment: Per https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller, it seems to be `var delegate: UIDocumentBrowserViewControllerDelegate?`

Comment: must be `weak var delegate: UIDocumentBrowserViewControllerDelegate?` instead

Answer (score 0):

The navigation stack seems at the heart of this. In the iOS 10 version, a collection view controller is the root view controller and is embedded in a navigation controller via storyboard.

In the iOS 11 version, the document browser view controller is the root view controller and cannot be embedded in a navigation controller. When I presented in the original code, my document view controller became the navigation stack's root view controller, and that cannot be popped, for example.

So I figured that maybe the navigation controller needed a different root view controller to mimic the prior behavior as much as possible and require the fewest code changes.

So I changed

```
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myController)
            self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to

```
                    let dummyVC = UIViewController()
                    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: dummyVC)
                    from.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    dummyVC.navigationController?.pushViewController(myController, animated: true)
```

This nav controller setup added a back button, meaning I didn't have to add a back button, and that handled popping the view controller automatically. As a result, I only needed to dismiss the nav controller, since it wasn't the app's root vc.

Finally, for the comment that the delegate should be declared weak, that's Apple's doing, and I just use it as provided. I'm not sure what affect that's having on things.

Comment: what is "from"? I don't see it anywhere else in your code?

Comment: I'll tell you where it's 'from', but I haven't looked at that code in months, so can't explain it all or recreate thought process without diving back into it. I added an extension to my UIDocument subclass with this method:     `@available(iOS 11.0, *)
    func present(from: DocumentBrowserViewController) {`
and that property is a parameter to the method.

Comment: its ok, I ended up using `self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)` and that seemed to work. How did you dismiss the pushViewController ? did you detect when the back button was pushed or maybe viewWillDisappear and then called `dummyVC.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` I'm guessing??

Comment: The view controller associated with the document has its `viewWillDisappear` method called automatically, and in there check its `navigationController` property and `.dismiss` that. The biggest complexity in all that is supporting iOS 10.x and iOS 11.x+, requiring parallel mechanisms be/c of the different document browser mechanisms.