# Check if view controller is presented modally or pushed, ( using swift), but i dont know what for?

Tags: swift, xcode, pushviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

> This code i got from my friend. But i don't know how it work. I hope some one in here can help me to explain this code. Because i have to explain it to my teacher.

```
    private func isModal() -> Bool {
    if self.presentingViewController != nil {
        return true
    } else if self.navigationController?.presentingViewController?.presentedViewController == self.navigationController  {
        return true
    } else if self.tabBarController?.presentingViewController is UITabBarController {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

> thanks :D

Comment: Your friend copied the code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/27301207/1187415.

Comment: Ask your "Friend" to explain you this code...Also tell me what you have asked him to provide you?

Comment: @MartinR .. yeah .. that is true .. hi hi but she is not understant too, abaut this code :D

Comment: @vivek ha ha .. good idea

Comment: that is .. chek ..a present modaly .. but i don't can to explaint it

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain you.

When you call **.isModel()** function from any class it will check and return you bool value according.

First condition which means of presentingview controller is initialized then it will return true.

The code is only to check if any class is presented or not