# SwiftUI - Setting NavBar items based on Sheet or NavigationLink presentation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view that is presented via sheet and navigation link. How can I tell if a view was shown via a Sheet or NavigationLink so that I can update my NavBar buttons appropriately? Right now, I'm using an "isModal" bool. It works, but is far from elegant. Building the navbar in the presenting view doesn't seem like a good solution. Is there a better way?  Basically the same as this question except using SwiftUI [How to check if a view controller is presented modally or pushed on a navigation stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620276/how-to-check-if-a-view-controller-is-presented-modally-or-pushed-on-a-navigation?rq=1)

Comment: Would you provide your code?

Comment: @Asperi It's this same question except using SwiftUI. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620276/how-to-check-if-a-view-controller-is-presented-modally-or-pushed-on-a-navigation?rq=1