# How to know tab bar is visible in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I tried to find out any way to figure out how to know the visibility of the tab bar, but not getting the exact answer.

Please let me know If you have got any idea.

I got some answer like checking the visibility by using the viewDidAppear and viewDidDisappear method of the tab bar controller sub class, but I want to know a genuine answer.
Thanks

Comment: `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden` might do the trick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if tabBar is visible on iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206838/check-if-tabbar-is-visible-on-ios-app)

Answer (score 1):

Swift solution:

```
if let tabBarCont = tabBarController {
   if tabBarCont.tabBar.isHidden == true {
      //do some stuff
    }
}
```