# In a UIViewController on the navigation stack, how do you detect that the tabbar is visible and get a reference to it?

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

The code below seems to only work if the viewcontroller is child of the tabbarcontroller.

```
var tabHeight: Int {
  if let tabBar = self.tabBarController?.tabBar {
    if !tabBar.isHidden { return tabBar.frame.height }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if tabBar is visible on iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206838/check-if-tabbar-is-visible-on-ios-app)